# What is it mean by "Operation applicable on object"/ "Operations on object"?

Tags: oop

I am most of the time confused with that terminology in OOP (inheritance). So lemme end my war with it today :)

consider the (language independent) code :

```
class rectangle {
...
  void changeLength(int);
  void changeWidth(int);
...
}

class square : public rectangle { ... }

int calculateArea(rectangle){ ... }
```

**Now when xyz says that any operation applicable ( or applies to) on `rectangle` is also applicable on `square` , is xyz talking about member functions here or (any manipulation of rectangle in ) `calculateArea` function or both included ?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

Comment: @SLaks I am not asking pitfalls in my example design) , read the title again?

Comment: I know.  I was just alerting you to the pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

When xyz says that any operation that is *provided by* by a `rectangle` is also *provided by* a `suqare`, he is talking about all three operations. `square` provides `calculateArea`, `changeLength(ing)` and `changeWidth(int)`.

When xyz says that any operation that is *applicable* to a `rectangle` is also *applicable* to a `square`, he is talking about the fact that `calculateArea(rectangle)` can also be called passing in an instance of a `square`. `calculateArea` itself then can call the public methods of the class. It will execute the methods of the superclass if these are not overridden in the subclass.

See also [Wikipedia: Inheritance (Computer Science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29)

Be sure to also read the Wikipedia article mentioned by SLaks about the [Circle-Ellipse-Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem) which addresses some major issues with this principle.

Comment: but when we'll manipulate the object in `calculateArea` , ultimately we will be calling members (methods in this case) of it to change it's state? (ignoring any environmental side effects)

Comment: Huh - maybe that's kind of a bad example here. `calculateArea` hopefully won't manipulate the object - we're just calculating the area, not changing it. However 'calculateArea' _will of course use members_ (fields or methods) of the superclass to fulfill its purpose.

Comment: Assume addition of `changeArea` ? , so doesn't things ultimately end to member methods?

Comment: I don't seem to understand the problem. The method `changeArea` can of course call members (fields *and methods*) of both the superclass and itself.

Comment: would you mind noticing that `changeArea` and `calculateArea` are not member function?